# String referencing parts of another string? Java

Tags: java, string, debugging, reference

I may be way off of the mark here but looking at the following debugging output, I can see that `line.value` is referencing the same string as `name.value` (id=70). The two strings only differ by `.count`. What sort of code would output similar results? Is this also a result of optimisation? (Sorry in advance if this is a bit of a silly/inappropriate question).
[image]

Comment: I see an arrow next to `value`...can you click that?

Comment: Yep, it is a char[] containing the string value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically `String.substring()` would do that. Or `trim()`. (Although there are surely others too, it's just the most obvious example. )

Since `String`s are immutable, it is safe to refer to another string's internal char array to avoid having to create lots of redundant copies of the same character data.

Answer (score 1):

As you're seeing, a Java string consists of a backing `char[]`, along with `offset` and `count` fields specifying the portion of the `char[]` behind this string.

This allows methods like `substring()`, which returns a portion of the string it's called on, to quickly return a smaller string without actually copying the characters.

Comment: String implementations are JVM dependent.  This is how Sun originally chose to do it in their JVM.